# Spark AR does not approve my effect, what's the reason?

Tags: augmented-reality, virtual-reality, spark-ar-studio

I just started using this software.  It is quite easy to create a cool effect. Moving on, I'm getting married next year and the wedding shower is gonna be next Saturday. I decided to create an instagram filter so my guests could use the filter while taking random pictures in the event. However, the effect is not getting approved by the platform to be published. It says, excessive text in the video sample. But it does not have excessive text. I have seen some effects around with tons of text, more than my effect does. Mine has not more than 5 short words.

The art of my effect was created on photoshop and imported to spark ar. I used photoshop to create a stroke text and add an emoji. Not big deal. However, as said before every time I submit the effect, it gets refused.

[I took a screenshot of my effect, take a look. it is all good.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zp5Xu.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

So sorry this wasn't answered in time.
Hopefully, this helps someone in future

Make sure face tracking is enabled for the texture so it's dynamic for the blue text part.
For the laughing and poop emojis, you can have them as stickers or as textures with face tracking.
Also, it would have been better if you used [particles](https://sparkar.facebook.com/ar-studio/learn/tutorials/adding-particle-systems/) and used the hearts as textures then adjust the speed, number, lifespan, and size of the particles

There are effects with lots of words, mostly because of bypassing the bots that assist in approval.